create migrations in an unit test project
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project with EF Core and a SQL Server database using the repository pattern. All works fine.
I added to the solution an xUnit test project and referenced the Web API project. I also added the appr. EF Core nuget packages also to this project. For this test project I also created a test database, because I don't want to use in-memory database and other technologies.
My goal is to add migrations to the test db and use the test database the same way as in the API project.
For this I added an appsettings.json to the test project and defined the connection string and I also added a context class to the test project:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace PlanProApiTest.Data
{
    public class PlanProTestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public PlanProTestDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlanProTestDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<PlanProApi.Models.Admin.Action> Actions { get; set; }
    }
}

Then I tried to run the command
add-migration Initial -startupproject PlanProTest

but I get an error:

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost.andUnable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[PlanProApiTest.Data.PlanProTestDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'PlanProApiTest.Data.PlanProTestDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

I assume I have to register somehow the PlanProTestDbContext. But how?
I'm relative new to unit test, so my question may be sound dumb. I even don't know, what is the entry point of a unit test project.

In tests, a common solution is to use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method.
